# jQuery: equivalent of .live() for CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

How do I add CSS to elements that have been dynamically created?

Here is a simple example of what I would like to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#container').html('<p id="hello">hello world</p>');
    // The following line doesn't work. 
    $('#hello').css("background-color", "#FFF");
});
```

The reason I want to do this, and I can't think of another way of doing it, is that I want to use background colour on alternate rows of a table that is dynamically generated:

```
$("#results-table tr:even").css("background-color", "#FFF");
```

I need to use this line of jQuery specifically for IE8 and below, which don't support `nth-child` CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code does work. You might want to check if you don't have multiple elements by that ID.

**Edit:**
Here's your code, without duplicate IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/FhTU7/

**Final edit:**
Your HTML background and element background are both white.

Comment: It doesn't work for me here, but maybe I'm just doing something idiotic: http://jsfiddle.net/WQRYw/4/

Comment: Both the backgrounds of HTML and your new element are white.

Comment: You are setting the background color to white. It's already white.

Comment: Yes, I am doing something idiotic :) background-color set to white. Sorry to waste your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could instead of directly setting the CSS also just add a class to the even rows

```
$("#results-table tr:even").addClass("alt");
```

CSS to set the row colours and then a different set of colours for the alternate rows

```
<style type="text/css">
tr
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

tr.alt
{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: +1 This is the automatic way to do it - most equivalent to `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the new element as a variable...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $new = $('<p id="hello">hello world</p>');
    $new.css({
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
    })
    $('#container').append($new);
});
```

You could use appendTo...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('<p id="hello">hello world</p>').appendTo('#container').css({
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
    })
});
```

However, if you create the elements correctly then you can use the original CSS at the end...

```
    $('#container').append('<p id="hello">hello world</p>');
```